# Change column value based on difference of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
    timestamp        type        value
0   1629453592426    0           10
1   1629453594429    0           120000
2   1629453654582    0           110000
3   1629453658662    1           22
4   1629453661342    1           44
5   1629453686644    0           115000
6   1629453689849    0           50
```

I want the `value` values to be 0 when the `timestamp` difference with the previous row is less than 60000 if the `value` is greater than 100000 or less than -100000 provided that `type` didn't change.

So the expected output is:

```
    timestamp        type        value
0   1629453592426    0           10
1   1629453594429    0           0
2   1629453654582    0           110000
3   1629453658662    1           22
4   1629453661342    1           44
5   1629453686644    0           115000
6   1629453689849    0           50
```

I tried to do it by creating a `timestamp_jump` column with:

```
df["timestamp_jump"] = df["timestamp"].diff().gt(60000).cumsum()
```

And then grouping the dataframe by `timestamp_jump` and `type` columns:

```
df.groupby(["timestamp_jump", "type"])[["value"]]
```

But couldn't figure out how to do the other steps. How can I achieve my expected dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
df.loc[df['type'].eq(df['type'].shift())
       & df['timestamp'].diff().lt(60000)
       & df['value'].abs().gt(100000), 'value'] = 0
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       timestamp  type   value
0  1629453592426     0      10
1  1629453594429     0       0
2  1629453654582     0  110000
3  1629453658662     1      22
4  1629453661342     1      44
5  1629453686644     0  115000
6  1629453689849     0      50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set group of consecutive same `type` by `.cumsum()` on current row `type` not equal to previous row `type`.

Then use [`.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) on the 2 conditions:

1. `value` > 100000 or < -100000
2. `timestamp` difference < 60000 (within the same group of consecutive same `type`)

to change `value` to `0`, as follows:

```
# set group of consecutive same `type`
g = df['type'].ne(df['type'].shift()).cumsum()

df['value'] = (df['value'].mask(
                                df['value'].abs().gt(100000) &
                                df.groupby(g)["timestamp"].diff().lt(60000)
                                , 0)
              )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

       timestamp  type   value
0  1629453592426     0      10
1  1629453594429     0       0
2  1629453654582     0  110000
3  1629453658662     1      22
4  1629453661342     1      44
5  1629453686644     0  115000
6  1629453689849     0      50
```

Comment: OP edited his post: `is greater than 100000 or less than -100000`

Comment: And I don't think you need a groupby for `timestamp`.

Comment: @Corralien  It's groupby the consecutive same `type`.  I assumed the 2 sequences of type 0 are to be treated as separate groups.

Comment: Check my answer, I'm sure you will understand.

Comment: @Corralien I see. That's simpler.  You got my upvote.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over all the rows in the df using `iterrows()` and then applying the condintions on current row and previous row, as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['timestamp'] = [1629453592426, 1629453594429, 1629453654582, 1629453658662, 1629453661342, 1629453686644, 1629453689849]
df['type'] = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
df['value'] = [10,120000,110000,22,44,115000,50]

df

timestamp   type    value
0   1629453592426   0   10
1   1629453594429   0   120000
2   1629453654582   0   110000
3   1629453658662   1   22
4   1629453661342   1   44
5   1629453686644   0   115000
6   1629453689849   0   50


for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if index!=0:
        current_timestamp = row['timestamp']
        prev_timestamp = list(df.iloc[[index-1]]['timestamp'])[0]
        current_val = row['value']
        current_type = row['type']
        prev_type = list(df.iloc[[index-1]]['type'])[0]
        if (abs(current_timestamp - prev_timestamp)<60000) and current_val>100000 and (current_type==prev_type):
            df.at[index,'value']=0

df

timestamp   type    value
0   1629453592426   0   10
1   1629453594429   0   0
2   1629453654582   0   110000
3   1629453658662   1   22
4   1629453661342   1   44
5   1629453686644   0   115000
6   1629453689849   0   50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    if (df.timestamp[i] - df.timestamp[i-1]) < 60000:
        df.value[i] = 0
    if abs(df.timestamp[i] - df.timestamp[i-1]) > 100000 & (df.type[i] == df.type[i-1]):
        df.value[i] = 0
```